# How can Task A create a new build variables to be consumed by task B in the same Task Group (TG) without exposing it outside of the TG?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Task Group with two tasks:

1. Set BinLogFlag
2. Compile Solution

The first task is actually another TG that sets BinLogFlag="/bl:...", if binary log is requested. It basically run the following Powershell code:

```
"##vso[task.setvariable variable=BinLogFlag]..."
```

Now **Compile Solution** is simply the MSBuild task with the following command line:

```
/m /v:m $(BinLogFlag)
```

So, to recap - **Set BinLogFlag** creates the build variable BinLogFlag and **Compile Solution** uses it. Of course, if BinLogFlag is empty, then no binary log is generated.

The problem is that the moment I add `$(BinLogFlag)` to the command line, Azure DevOps adds it to the parameters of the TG I develop:
[image]

But it is an internal implementation detail. I do not want it exposed. My current workaround is fragile - I updated/generate Directory.Build.rsp file before compiling and delete/restore it afterwards.

I do not like it at all. Is it possible for **Compile Solution** to use the `BinLogFlag` build variable created by **Set BinLogFlag** without exposing it as yet another parameter of the parent Task Group?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for Compile Solution to use the BinLogFlag build variable created by Set BinLogFlag without exposing it as yet another parameter of the parent Task Group?

The answer is Yes.

There is a feature for Task Group: **Export** after we create the task group:

[image]

Export it, you will get the `.json` file and open it with notepad or Visual Studio, you will get following code segment about parameter :

```
  "iconUrl": "https://cdn.vsassets.io/v/M154_20190723.10/_content/icon-meta-task.png",
  "friendlyName": "TestTG",
  "description": "",
  "category": "Build",
  "definitionType": "metaTask",
  "author": "YourCount",
  "demands": [],
  "groups": [],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "aliases": [],
      "options": {},
      "properties": {},
      "name": "",
      "label": "",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "required": true,
      "type": "string",
      "helpMarkDown": "",
      "groupName": ""
    }
  ],
  "satisfies": [],
```

**Then**, we delete the content in the inputs to `[]`, so it looks like:

```
  "groups": [],
  "inputs": [],
  "satisfies": [],
```

Finally, we import this `.json` back to the task group and rename it with a new name `Set BinLogFlag V2`.

When we add this task group to the pipeline to create the another task group **Compile Solution**, the `BinLogFlag` build variable created by set **BinLogFlag** will **not be exposed**:

[image]

I use the command line task instead of MSBuild in your demo to test if the value of the variable `BinLogFlag` can be passed correctly. And it works fine as test.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It definitely helps. But what happens when I modify the Task Group by doing some unrelated modification to it? Will BinLogFlag parameter reappear and I will be forced to repeat the export/import trick?

Comment: @mark, Indeed, it will reappear again if you modofiy the task group `BinLogFlag`, but it will not show the value, it only show `This setting is required.`, you can ignore it, because it will not appear when you add it in the build pipeline. In general, above answer should be a workaround not a best solution. You could submit this request to the MS team.

Comment: I would like to submit this request. Do you have the link?

Comment: Actually the workaround is not appropriate when the task is already used by many builds, because doing the export/import thing removes this task which would require me to update all the affected builds.

Comment: @mark, You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/666362/allow-task-a-to-create-a-new-build-variable-to-be.html

Comment: @mark, I have voted it up and follow it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: Great, my request for this feature was closed for lack of interest from the community.