# How to expose a Task Group parameter, if it is not detected as the TG dependency by Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

Consider the following Task Group:

[image]

So, EnableSonarQube controls if the task runs. But Azure DevOps does not recognize it as a parameter. It does work fine if I declare a build variable under the name of EnableSonarQube, but that variable implicitly controls all the instances of this TG in the build.

So, how can I cause Azure DevOps to recognize it and provide me with the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I cause Azure DevOps to recognize it and provide me with the parameter?

Indeed, this is a known Task Group limitation, which Variables values do not extract for Task group parameters in Azure Devops.

You could get similar issue from: [Powershell task does not expose variables to a task group](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9482)

As workaround, we could add another task to display variables, so that it could be passes the default value as a parameter:

[image]

Then, when we use this task in the build pipeline, we could overwrite it, and its scope of action is limited to task group:

[image]

**Update:**

As the workaround I provided in [your previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57207859/how-can-task-a-create-a-new-build-variables-to-be-consumed-by-task-b-in-the-same), we can also use the same method to modify the `.json` file to add the parameter in the `inputs`:

Change

```
 "inputs": []
```

to

```
  "inputs": [
    {
      "aliases": [],
      "options": {},
      "properties": {},
      "name": "EnableSonarQube",
      "label": "EnableSonarQube",
      "defaultValue": "True",
      "required": true,
      "type": "string",
      "helpMarkDown": "",
      "groupName": ""
    }
  ],
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: And the same comment applies - does this workaround persistent? I.e. will I not be forced to do it every time I modify the Task Group?

Comment: @mark, The answer is yes. You do not need to be forced to do it every time you modify the Task Group. This question is different from the previous one. **The default setting of the task group parameters is exposed.**, so it won't go away when you modify the task group. As I test, it works fine.

Comment: Exporting/Importing has a problem of replacing the task with a new one, which forces us to update manually all the affected builds. Cannot do that.